# Obfuscating Exe before making clickonce installer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, obfuscation

I am ready to publish my application using clickonce. Although I need to obfuscate my application too. I was thinking of using dotfuscator that comes with VS 2010. Now my question is do I have to build my project then obfuscate it then create a new solution with just a  clickonce project and add the obfuscated files into it? Or do I add the clickonce project to my applications solution, like I normally would and just add the obfuscated assemblies to it? Sorry this is all new to me. Both obfuscation and clickonce. Also I have not compiled my project yet, is there a way to add the projects into the clickonce project in my solution and build it all at once? Or again does it have to be built first then added to the clickonce project? Sorry for all the questions, I am a beginner and I couldn't find much info on it.

Answer (score 0):

just obfuscate the executable by the way if you have any libraries that you had to make for the project , obfuscate them too :)

i prefer encrypting the exe with a powerful algorithm and obfuscate it ..

Answer (score 0):

The deepsea obfuscator works with clickonce